# Dropdown it shows option on hover

Tags: javascript, php

I Have a dropdown it shows option on click only but i need on hover display option

```
<label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
                <select onhover="setLocation(this.value)" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sort By')) ?>">

                    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                        </option>
                            </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                </select>
```

Comment: little CSS thing called `:hover`.

Comment: If i set display none then it won't work hover also

Comment: you need to use javascript in that case then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something as simple as this:
https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/v2064L95/

`showHideDD()` is the function in which you toggle your dropdown.
Then you just bind the `click`, `mouseover`and `mouseout`events.
Or to be a bit clearer, you can do:

```
$("#myid,#dd").click(showHideDD);
$("#myid,#dd").mouseover(showHideDD);
$("#myid,#dd").mouseout(showHideDD);
```